# Electron & NodeJS chat server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, chat, electron

I am currently working on an assignment for school, and it basically consists of an Electron app, which doubles as a client and a host for a chat application. Would anybody know how to set up a pure (vanilla) JavaScript `XHttpRequest` loop to constantly check for new messages AND send them? Also, how would I handle the incoming messages in Node?

Comment: Why XHttpRequest and not WebSockets? There are plenty WebSocket based chats, like this :https://gist.github.com/martinsik/2031681 for example.

Comment: I have tried using socket.io, but it has proved to be too difficult to get the server IP on the client's computer so it can connect to it and declare the io variable...

Comment: What I want to do, is just have a POST handler in the server, and just a vanilla JavaScript ajax request to check for messages...

Comment: So the app is the client and the server? Wouldn't the server address be `http://localhost:[port]`

Comment: Yes, but I need to program it so it works as well when the server is someone else's... The way I had created the connection to other servers, was to have someone type in the IP into a text box and save it for later use in that session. How would I pass that into the AJAX call?